# $S_5 = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}, |x − 5| \leq 12 \}$ is an open or closed set?

Tags: general-topology

I've got a question that asks whether $S_5 = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}, |x − 5| \leq 12 \}$ is an open or closed set.

In my opinion, it is a closed set, because it has a boundary of $x = 0$ and $y = 0.$ But I'm still not sure, can anyone help me figure out the answer of this question?

Comment: Open or closed where? In $\mathbb{N}?$ Every set in $\mathbb{N}$ is closed and open. Or are you asking in $\mathbb{R}?$

Comment: Why did you tag this [tag:education] and [tag:economics]?!

Comment: ow, sorry I made a typo, its suppose to be element of R @SahibaArora

Comment: @JadenLiu Please edit the question to correct it.

Comment: @SahibaArora done. can you help me to answer it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a subset of $\mathbb{N}$, it is both open and closed since every subset of $\mathbb{N}$ is both open and closed (in discrete topology).

As a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ with usual topology, it is closed and not open because it is a finite set, namely $\{x \in \mathbb{N} : 0\leq x\leq 17\}.$

If you mean to ask whether $\{x \in \mathbb{R} : |x-5|\leq 12\}$ is open/closed in $\mathbb{R},$ in that case $S_5 = \{x \in \mathbb{R}:-7\leq x \leq 17\}=[-7,17]$ which is closed interval.

Comment: Thank you very much!